# AMQPLIB - NodeJS - Asserting a Lazy Queue in RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I want to `assert a queue in lazy mode into existence` via amqplib using nodeJs.

I know I can do this by creating policies, I don't want to do that as its hard to automate right now in the environment we have.

I have tried the following:

```
        let options = {
            durable: true,
            arguments: {},
            lazy: true, //doesnt work
            mode: "lazy" //doesnt work
        };
        if (job.highQueueLengthExpected) {
            options.arguments["x-queue-mode"] = "lazy"; //doesnt work
            options.arguments["queue-mode"] = "lazy"; //doesnt work
            options["x-queue-mode"] = "lazy"; //doesnt work
        }

        return ch.assertQueue(job.key, options).then(function (ok) {
```

I am `checking the mode` of the queue via RabbitMQ's HTTP API by firing

```
curl  -u guest:guest 'localhost:15672/api/queues/{vhostName}/{queueName}'
```

For all the options I provide while asserting the queue, the `mode comes back as default`

Answer (score 1):

`queueMode: 'lazy'`

works for me. In general I think the amqplib option keys are the camel-cased versions of the amqp features or options with the `x-` removed. For example `x-dead-letter-exchange` in amqp is `deadLetterExchange` in amqplib.

This only works with amqplib v0.5.3 and higher.